Would being in a simulation explain why we have regularities?
Would being in a simulation explain why reality exhibits regularities or would that just bring the question back a notch and ask how that simulation came about?
We live in a world that seems to be prescribed by certain laws. Now you may take the view that laws are merely descriptions and don’t have causal power, but the point is that whatever matter contains or however it behaves, it exhibits regular behavior even though there is no apriori reason to do this.
There are more ways to imagine mechanics of objects exhibiting no patterns than there are ways for them to exhibit consistent, unbreakable patterns. Would simulation theory explain this?

if the real world does not have consistent physics, how on earth did the Architects manage to create a simulation?

I never said that the real world doesn’t have consistent physics. But good point!

It would do both, explain the regularities and move the question to who set up the simulation. But that is the case with all explanations, after every because there is another why. When Newton explained falling bodies and planetary motions by universal gravity the question moved to what gravity is. Nonetheless, it was an informative explanation. If it were to be established that we do live in a simulated environment that would be informative as well, regardless of further why-s.

That is true. @Conifold But I think the reason why people point out explanatory regress is not because if an explanation is true, it wouldn’t be informative. I think it’s to point out that if we don’t have independent evidence for it, it is no better than just asserting that the status quo happened without further explanation.

You never said it but it's a basic implication of your question: if you need the Simulation to explain the regularities, how do you explain those of the real world the simulation was built into? It just shows that the Simulation wouldn't explain anything.

You asked what a simulation would explain, not whether we have grounds to posit it as the explanation. And the nature of regularities in a simulation is likely entirely different from their nature in the simulator's world, so there is no regress in the spirit of homunculus fallacy either, if that is what you had in mind.

That’s not the fallacy I had in mind but what I did have in mind is whether the simulator itself would need explanation, but as you pointed out, it would ask for further explanation while also being informative if it was true. @armand I suppose it depends on what you mean by explain. As Conifold and I were discussing, if the simulation was demonstrated, it would still explain why we have these regularities even if we don’t figure out what’s happening in the simulator’s world

Why would simulation explain it?????

If we were in a simultion, the universe in which the simulation is implemented would have to have regularities too, in order to implement something upon which to run a simulation. So it would explain our regularities, sure, but would also posit more regularities to explain.
I would lean towards this NOT being a preferrable explanation without extra evidence in favor of the simulation idea.

In general, the proposition that we are in a simulation could explain anything you want it to explain. You would simply have to stipulate the characteristics of the simulation to be those that we happen to observe.

As a metaphysical theory or explanation, it offers no help (as shown in the comments) - it merely pushes the question further up the causal chain.
As an epistemological thesis, it is similar to the long-running "Brain in a Vat" arguments on content externalism. Can we know that we are not in a simulation? Can we know that we are not just a brain in a vat?
If the simulation is sufficiently accurate it's hard to see how we'd ever have any hope of knowing it is so.
As with most philosophical topics, there is no conclusive answer to all forms of the skeptical argument that we cannot know we are not a brain-in-a-vat.
However, Hilary Putnam give's one successful argument, assuming we accept both the Closure Principal (widely held) and a new premise called the "causal constraint":
Note: All material below pulled from
McKinsey, Michael, "Skepticism and Content Externalism", The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy (Spring 2024 Edition), Edward N. Zalta & Uri Nodelman (eds.), URL = https://plato.stanford.edu/archives/spr2024/entries/skepticism-content-externalism/.

Closure Principle:
Tge widely endorsed closure  principle that knowledge is closed under known entailments:
(CL)  For all persons S and propositions p and q, if S knows that p,
and S knows that p entails q, then S knows that q.


Causal Constraint
The crucial move in Putnam’s argument is a sub-argument to the effect
that that if one were a BIV, one would not be able to grasp the
meanings of various general terms, such as ‘tree’, ‘brain’, and ‘vat’.
For in order for an utterance of ‘tree’ for example to represent or
refer to trees, Putnam maintains, there must be some causal connection
between uses of ‘tree’ and real trees (Putnam 1981 [1999: 37]).
Following Wright (1992: 71), I will call this ‘the causal constraint’.


Argument from closure and causal constraint:
[While it] is doubtful whether Putnam’s causal constraint alone can be used to
show, in a manner that does not beg the question, that any arbitrary
person is not a BIV. However, it is possible to show, using Putnam’s
causal constraint, that the argument (SA) for skepticism mentioned
above that uses both the BIV scenario and the closure principle (CP)
is, in a sense, self defeating. Here, recall, is (SA):
(SA) 
(1) You know that the proposition that you have a body entails
that you are not a brain in a vat. [Premise] 
∴ (2)   If you know that
you have a body, then you know that you are not a brain in a vat. [By
(1) and (CL)]     (3) But you don’t know that you are not a brain in a
vat. [Premise] ∴  (4) You don’t know that you have a body. [By (2) and
(3)]      In their arguments against skepticism, Putnam and his defenders
have been mainly concerned with providing arguments against premise
(3) of (SA). But in fact, Premise 1 of the skeptical argument itself
may provide the best reason for doubting Premise 3 of that argument.
For consider the following anti-skeptical argument (AS):

(AS)      (1) You know that the proposition that you have a body entails
that you are not a brain in a vat. [Premise (1) of (SA)]  ∴ (2)   You
have the concept of a BIV. [By (1)]   (3) But no BIV has the concept of
a BIV. [By the causal constraint.]  ∴     (4) You are not a BIV. [By (2),
(3)]  (The inference from (1) to (2) here requires two additional, and
I hope obvious, assumptions: (1a) Knowing a proposition requires
having the concepts necessary for thinking the proposition, and (1b)
The concept of a BIV is one by which the known proposition is
grasped.)

Of course, the conclusion (4) of (AS) (“You are not a BIV”) does not
imply that you know that you are not a BIV. However, note that all of
the other anti-skeptical arguments considered so far also have this
feature; they all have the conclusion that the relevant agent is not a
BIV. It is then inferred that the agent knows that she is not a brain
in a vat by virtue of her having deduced the conclusion that she is
not a BIV from premises that she knows, always including assumed
knowledge of the causal constraint.
In this manner, any agent to whom the skeptical argument (SA) is
addressed may also reason through the argument (AS) to the conclusion
that she is not a BIV and then to the further conclusion that she
knows that she is not a BIV, and hence that premise (3) of the
skeptical argument is false. Thus in any such case, if the relevant
instance of premise (1) of (SA) is true, then the corresponding
instance of premise (3) will be false. Thus in any such case, the
skeptical argument will be shown to have at least one false premise,
and the argument (relative to the addressed person) will have been
refuted.
Note that there can be no issue of question-begging in an
anti-skeptical argument like this. First, it is not the person to whom
the skeptical argument is being addressed who is assuming premise (1)
of both (SA) and (AS). Rather, it is the skeptic who is making that
assumption. Second, the person being addressed can be taken to be
assuming premise (1) merely for the sake of conditional proof. That
is, she can be taken to be arguing merely for the conclusion that if
premise (1) is true then premise (3) is false, so that at least one of
argument (SA)’s premises is false.
It would seem, then, that Putnam’s causal constraint, if it is in fact
true, can be used to refute the skeptical argument that is based on
both the BIV scenario and the closure principle (CP).


I don't think that regularities would prove that we are in a simulation. However irregularities might be proof. If magic were proven to be possible, If ghosts were proven to exist. In other words if things were found that could only exist in a simulation.

This is a great question.
But we need to separate apples and oranges and specifically point out which regularities we are talking about.
To start with, any computer program or a simulator is practically impossible without regularities. Otherwise, without regular repetition, you would have to hard-code trillions upon trillion scenarios.
But, as the architect of The Matrix appropriately noticed, life needs irregularities, life is not a mechanical machine, people will stop playing the game of life if everything is regular and predictable.
Further down, in our world, we can readily find unexplained regularities in very small and very large.
Quantum physics is full of unexplained but consistent behaviors occurring only when being examined.
In the history of humanity as well as in individual life, it is hard not to notice unexplainable regularities.
The verdict? Simulator it is.
